# Give spacing to adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

Tags: swift, swift3

My problem is quite simple. I'm using `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` with a button, and it is working fine, however, the button has a border and there is ugly overlap between the text and the border.

Is it possible to give spacing between button border and text in this manner?

edit:
Here is photo of my problem.

[image: photo of problem]

also, a solution that doesn't use adjust the font size to fit width at all is fine as long as it provides the same functionality.

Comment: Can you provide a photo?

Comment: try changing contentEdgeInsets or titleEdgeInsets

Comment: @sarojraut AWESOME EXACTLY WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR make an answer for it so that others can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `contentEdgeInsets` or `titleEdgeInsets`.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this depends on you.

1. Increase the size of your button. After setting `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to true and the button title, set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` back to false, and then increase the size of your button.
2. Reduce the size of your button title. After setting `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to true and the button title, set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` back to false. Now check the font size of your title and then decrease it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am wondering if this will slow down my program as I am updating the button's text every second